# php preg_replace regex replace string between two string

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

I have the following problem: I want to replace (in php) a special character, but only if it's between two other characters. It tried to find a solution with with preg_replace but it doesn't work.

I want to replace every ; with a : which is between the "
The Examples:

```
$orig_string= 'asbas;"asd;";asd;asdadasd;"asd;adsas"'
```

result should be:

```
'asbas;"asd:";asd;asdadasd;"asd:adsas"'
```

I tried several regexes but without any succes...

Two examples i tried:

```
$result = preg_replace('(?<=\")(.*)(;)(.*)(?=\")',':', $str);

$result = preg_replace('.*\".*(;).*\"',':', $str);
```

Can anybody help me?

Thanks a lot

V

Comment: Are the texts between two " some special texts that have a special meaning? Therefor @nu11p01n73R 's solution would not work correctly, as it doesn't take in account, that in the first part there could already be a " without a following ;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need not use look arounds here. It can be written as

```
("[^";]*);([^"]*")
```

replace with `\1:\2`

[**Regex Demo**](https://www.regex101.com/r/gR6kG9/1)

**Test**

```
preg_replace ("/(\"[^\";]*);([^\"]*\")/m", "\\1:\\2", 'asbas;"asd;";asd;asdadasd;"asd;adsas"' );
=> asbas;"asd:";asd;asdadasd;"asd:adsas"
```

**Update:**

```
;(?!(?:"[^"]*"|[^"])*$)
```

Just replace the matched `;` with `:`

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/bC8aZ4/13)

Comment: :-) not mistakenly. Revert it back if you don't want  ... no, don't do that.

Comment: not the good answer. It's the right answer because your's will fail if more than one semi colons present inside the quotes..

Comment: Great, the last one works for me, that was exactly what i'm looking for!! Thank you very much. It seemed to be that i'm not that fimiliar with all regex-Expression as I thought ;) And i tried to access the matches with "$1:$2" and not with double back slash.... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey, your answer helps me a lot and it works fine up to now... I found a possible combination in which this solution doesn't work correctly... I tried to modify your solution to run all variations but without any success.. If you have the following string 'asbas;asd:;asd;asdadasd;"asd:adsas' the regex replace all ; before the double qoutes... i would expect that the regex do nothing. It should only replace the ; within two double quotes. So i hope you can help me again! Thank's a lot.

Comment: The `m` pattern modifier is useless if there are no anchors in the pattern -- like `^` or `$`.

Answer (score 1):

```
;(?=[^"]*"(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

Try this.Replace by `:`.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/bC8aZ4/16

Answer (score 1):

A simple understandable solution could be the use of [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('/"[^"]+"/',
       function ($m) { return str_replace(";", ":", $m[0]); },
       $str);
```

`"[^"]+"` captures the quoted stuff to `$m[0]` where `;` is replaced by `:`

[See test at eval.in](https://eval.in/263326) (link will expire soon)

Answer (score -1):

What about string replace?

```
str_ireplace(';";', ':";', $orig_string);
```

> asbas;"asd:";asd;asdadasd;"asd;adsas"

Comment: In programming there's no one solution for one problem, you give 10 programmers a problem, the approach to the problem will be different with the same results, yet i see you got a thumb down for giving a solution to a problem with a different approach.

Comment: Your Solution replaces only a semicolon if it is followed by a " and another semicolon, but the second occurence in the example is not replaced, as it follows another pattern.