# php preg_replace regex replace character between two characters of a string

Tags: regex, preg-replace

i'm not sure if it's correct to ask a question twice. I have already asked the following question and i found a great solution. Unfortunatelly i found a combination which doesn't work with this solution. I tried a lot to modify the solution but i didn't work. I also added a comment, but it seemed to be that nobody remark that comment, why I have to ask my question again:

I want to replace a character in a string but only if this character is between two other characters. In my case i want to replace all ; which are between douple quotes.
Therefor i got some example strings:

> asbas;"asd;";asd;asdadasd;"asd;adsas"
>
> asbas;"asd:;a"sd;asdadasd;"asd:adsas;taras;adass
>
> "asbas";""asd:;a"sd";"asdadasd";""asd:adsas";"taras";"adass"

In my last question ([Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28169732/php-preg-replace-regex-replace-string-between-two-string/28170543#28170543)) i got the following solution:

```
preg_replace ("/(\"[^\";]*);([^\"]*\")/m", "\\1:\\2", 
                   'asbas;"asd;";asd;asdadasd;"asd;adsas"' );
```

This solution works great, but only in this case where the occurance of the doublequots are eval. So the first example-string works great, but not the second or third.

I also tried out:

```
preg_replace_callback('/"[^"]+"/',
   function ($m) { return str_replace(";", ":", $m[0]); },
   $str);
```

To clearify my question: I need a regex that works with the both example strings and give the following results:

> asbas;"asd:";asd;asdadasd;"asd:adsas"
>
> asbas;"asd::a"sd;asdadasd;"asd:adsas;taras;adass
>
> "asbas";""asd::a"sd";"asdadasd";""asd:adsas";"taras";"adass"

The replace should only take place when the semicolon is between the double quotes.

I thank you very much for your help and answers.

Kind regards

Markus

**EDIT:**
The background of my question is the pre preparation of csv-files. The are some combination where even excel don't know how to handle the file "correctly"... so i try to change some character and interpretate it as i know the file should be... so the column is one block of "..." and is delimitered with a semicolon. And know i want to change als semicolon between double-quotes-block... the problem occours if there is also a "-character in thie double-quotes-block. So i need regex which even find the semicolon in this block.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `preg_replace_callback()` and `str_replace()`. Consider the following code and explanation:

```
<?php
$str = '"asbas";""asd::a"sd";"asdadasd";""asd:adsas";"taras";"adass"';
echo "$str\n";          // prints out the string
$regex = '/([^"]+)/i';
// captures every character EXLUDING a double quote
// case-insensitive, must be more/equal to 1 character

$str = preg_replace_callback($regex, 
    function($matches) {
        return str_replace(';', '', $matches[0]);
        // replaces every semicolon with '' in the captured group
    },
        $str
    );

echo "$str\n";
// output: "asbas"""asd::a"sd""asdadasd"""asd:adsas""taras""adass"
?>
```

Comment: Hey jan. Thank's for your response. Unfortunatelly doesn't solve it my problem. Your solution delete every ; and i only want to delete the ; between the double quotes...Perhaps you can compare it my expected results.