# How to replace text that is only between two specific words

Tags: php, regex

I have a code that will replace some values with other ones using `preg_replace`,

```
$data = preg_replace($word, $replacement, $data);
```

`$word` and `$replacement` are arrays
,but I want to know is there any way to replace those values if they are between two words?
for example, what I want to replace here is (`TheOriginalWord ==> TheReplacement`):

```
hi          ==> bye
hello       ==> goodbye
hello there ==> see you later
```

but the word should be replaced only if it's between `!START` and `!END`:

```
hi
!START
hi
other words
hello there
word
!END
hello there
```

Should be converted to:

```
hi
!START
bye
other words
see you later
word
!END
hello there
```

I've already read a lot of other qustions and none of them helped me
(for example: [php preg_replace regex replace string between two string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28169732/php-preg-replace-regex-replace-string-between-two-string)
)

NOTE: The text that is not inside the `!START` and `!END` should be kept.

Comment: I think the simplest answer is to only apply a replacement to the text that is between those tags; meaning, when you actually 'get' that text, remove what you don't want to apply a replacement on, before preg_replace ever sees it. explode/implode could be your friend in this mission.

Comment: but I want to keep that text

Comment: it will be used for other reasons

Comment: `preg_replace_callback()` from the link you gave solves your problem - [solution](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7cf1579e510dea38f90d077b8188791ce81997ee)

Comment: You'd have to use a callback. The preg_replace_callback(), using this regex `(?s)!START(.*?)!END`, In the callback run another replacement preg_replace() with the array's on capture group 1, then return the result.

Comment: @x15 can you apply it to the code above?

Comment: Could write the whole thing but see demo's on using the callback, it's not that difficult.

Comment: please try to apply it to `$data = preg_replace($word, $replacement, $data);`

Comment: Click the link I gave you

Comment: @shudder what link?

Comment: Link titled "solution"

Comment: @shudder - `'#\!START.*?\!END#s` incase there is more than a single pair

Comment: @x15 Right. Need lazy capturing.

Comment: @shudder - You should post your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not easy to come up with a solution, but I think you can use something like this:

```
$string = 'hi !START hi hello there !END hello there';

function wordAndReplacement()
{
    return [
        'hi' => 'bye',
        'hello there' => 'see you later',
        'hello' => 'goodbye',
    ];
}

function returnSubstring($str)
{
    $substring = trim(substr($str, strpos($str, '!START') + 6));
    return trim(explode('!END', $substring)[0]);
}

function replace($str)
{
    $substring = returnSubstring($str);

    $newString = '';

    foreach (wordAndReplacement() as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos($substring, $key) !== false) {
            !empty($newString) ? $newString = str_replace($key, $value, $newString) : $newString = str_replace($key, $value, $substring);
        } elseif(strpos($substring, $value) !== false) {
            !empty($newString) ? $newString = str_replace($value, $key, $newString) : $newString = str_replace($value, $key, $substring);
        }
    }

    return $newString;
}

function joinStringAndReplacement($string)
{
    $initial = explode('!START', $string)[0];
    $final = substr($string, strpos($string, '!END') + 4);

    return $initial . replace($string) . $final;
}

echo joinStringAndReplacement($string);
```

Firstly, the `returnSubstring()` method simply returns the string in between !START and !END.

Then, the `wordAndReplacement()` method returns an array with words you want to replace on the string.

Lastly, there is a loop through wordAndReplacement array, to replace every word of the array found in the string with its replacement (either on its key or its value), using `str_replace()`.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: no, it removes the text outside of `!START` and `!END`, I want it to keep that text and just change the text inside of `!START` and `!END`

Comment: @EnderAdel It is a simple fix. Just added `joinStringAndReplacement()` method, concatenating the text outside with the replacement... now it is what you want?

Comment: @EnderAdel is it what you expect now?

Answer (score 1):

Pass your string to replace as `$subject`, `$replacements` in form of associative array with values to change as keys and expected result as value - `['find' => 'replace', 'another find' => 'another replace']` and `$start`/`$end` delimiters.

```
function replace_between(string $subject, array $replacements, string $start, string $end): string
{
    $replace = function ($match) use ($replacements) {
        return str_replace(array_keys($replacements), $replacements, $match[0]);
    };
    $pattern = '#' . preg_quote($start, '#') . '.*?' . preg_quote($end, '#') . '#s';
    return preg_replace_callback($pattern, $replace, $subject);
}
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/098df83ca3fe222e258b66ee6679bcf7bc05383a)

Comment: This is the simplest and best answer... thank you. Worked perfectly for me, even when the start and end words appear multiple times, like `hi
!START
hi
!END
other words
!START
hi
hello there
word
!END
hello there`. One caveat that might save someone some time: I was trying to replace line breaks. `PHP_EOL` didn't do it as the search term, but `'\r\n'` did.

Answer (score 0):

use regex:

```
$startSearch="!START";
$endSearch="!END";
$searchRegex = "/(?<=$startSearch) (?s).* (?=$endSearch)/";
$replace = " bye see you later ";
$input= "hi !START hi hello there !END hello there";
echo preg_replace ($searchRegex ,$replace,$input);
```

output

```
hi !START bye see you later !END hello there
```

notice:

> the regex here replaces everything between the first !START and !END very important to check what you need to do when "!START" or "!END" is duplicate in the same text

Comment: but what does determine what values should be replaced with?

Comment: your code just replaces all words inside !START and !END with the string you've put, this is not what I want