# php preg_replace regex replace matched characters in sub match

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to put spaces around +/- characters when they appear in between brackets in a string, only if the brackets have a "function" in front of them called "calc". e.g.

**The starting string**

```
some text;(some+other+text);calc(some+text-here);some+further-text
```

**The desired output**

```
some text;(some+other+text);calc(some + text - here);some+further-text
```

So using the following expression I can match the calc(*) section;

```
/(?:calc\([^\)]+\))+/m
```

And using the following expression I can match all +/- symbols, but not just those within the calc() function:

```
/[\+\-](?!(?:calc\([^\)]+\))+)/m
```

There's a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28169732/php-preg-replace-regex-replace-string-between-two-string) that I used to build the above, and it does what I'd want if I only wanted to match between brackets. But the moment I specify the extra "calc" it breaks.

Any further help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you may use `preg_replace('~(?:\G(?!\A)|\bcalc\()[^-)]*\K-(?=[^()]*\))~', ' - ', $string)`. However, what if there are spaces around a `-` already? Try also `preg_replace('~(?:\G(?!\A)|\bcalc\()(?:[^-)]*[^-)\s])?\K\s*-\s*(?=[^()]*\))~', ' - ', $string)`

Comment: Actually, you could start building on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28170543/3832970) as you already have a regex to match the whole function body.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm sure it can be done via regex, but as you note it's very simple using the preg_replace_callback, so I've done that. Thanks!